# How can I stop window.status from displaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following:

```
<a  class="button accessLink"
            id="loginLink"
            href="#"
            data-action="Login"
            data-dialog="access"
            data-disabled="false"
            data-entity="n/a"
            data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Login"
            title="Login">Login</a>
```

and:

```
$('.accessLink')
    .mouseover(function() {
        window.status = '';
    });
```

However when I mouseover the link above I still see

```
<my ip address>/#
```

Is there some other way I can stop this showing at the bottom of the browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about **not** using an anchor`<a>` tag altogether ?
Handle the click event of a `<span>` or a `<div>` element in jQuery and do a location.href to take the user to the link specified in element's data-href. That way, nothing would show up in status bar.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I will look into this.

Comment: This seems to work but now I notice when I hover over the button my cursor does not change to a pointer. Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status) would be disabled by default in most recent browsers. Consider the 
scenario where a malicious website could effectively impersonate a trusted entity:

```
<script>
$('#bad-link').mouseover(function() {
    window.status = 'www.microsoft.com';
});
</script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/something-bad" id="bad-link">Click me</a>
```

Also remember that *a lot* of browsers by default don't even display the status bar anymore!

Comment: but still show the URL moused over inside the browser window (FX and Chrome does that)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean "don't even display the status bar anymore". Latest versions of Firefox and Chrome display it.

Comment: @Gemma not by default on my boxes (XP/OSX) - however I see the full URL in the bottom of my screen

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

specify href="javascript:"

```
<a  class="button accessLink"
            id="loginLink"
            href="javascript:"
            data-action="Login"
            data-dialog="access"
            data-disabled="false"
            data-entity="n/a"
            data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Login"
            title="Login">Login</a>
```

Comment: Google Chrome shows :javascript at the bottom when I do this.

Comment: friend.. we cant do that. we must show atleast "javascript:" text.  otherwise, It would easy to phishing attacks a great deal to disguise the link.